# Orbeon 2018.1 fr-error-summary rendering issue

Tags: orbeon

It would appear that there is a rendering issue with fr-error-summary in Orbeon 2018.1 when you try to render the global errors:

```
<xhtml:table width="100%">
  <xhtml:tr>
    <xhtml:td>
     <fr:error-summary observer="generalTab" id="error-summary">
       <fr:label ref="$resources/please-handle-validation-errors"/>
       <fr:errors nodeset="instance('errors')/error">
         <fr:label ref="label"/>
         <fr:alert ref="alert"/>
       </fr:errors>
     </fr:error-summary>
   </xhtml:td>
 </xhtml:tr>
</xhtml:table>
```

This leads to the following rendering:

```
<li id="repeat-end-error-summary≡xf-2268" class="xforms-repeat-begin-end"></li>
<span id="error-summary≡xf-2272" class="xforms-group">...</span>
<table width="100%">...</table>
```

The `<span>` contains all the errors and the `<table>` contains only the fr:label as `<legend>`

I've added a side-by-side of the code between our production server on Orbeon 3.9 and my test using Orbeon 2018.1
[image: Orbeon 2018.1 left and Orbeon 3.9 right]

Included is a simple xform to reproduce it with.

```html
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title>orbeon-2018-1-fr-error-summary-rendering-issue</xh:title>
        <xf:model id="repro">
            <xf:instance id="test">
                <test>SUCCESS</test>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:bind nodeset="instance('test')" constraint=". = 'SUCCESS'"/>
            <xf:action ev:observer="test" ev:event="xxforms-value-changed">
                <xf:setvalue ref="instance('data-safe')">false</xf:setvalue>
                <xf:dispatch name="fr-visit-all" targetid="error-summary"/>
                <xf:refresh/>
                <xf:dispatch name="fr-update" targetid="error-summary"/>
                <xf:dispatch name="fr-visit-all" targetid="error-summary-global"/>
                <xf:refresh/>
                <xf:dispatch name="fr-update" targetid="error-summary-global"/>
            </xf:action>
        </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <xh:h3>TEST</xh:h3>
        <xf:group model="repro" id="validationArea">
            <xf:input ref="instance('test')" incremental="true">
                <xf:label>Enter any value other than SUCCESS to trigger an alert</xf:label>
                <xf:alert>You SHALL have SUCCESS</xf:alert>
            </xf:input>
        </xf:group>
        <xh:table>
            <xh:tr>
                <xh:td>
                    <fr:error-summary observer="validationArea" id="error-summary">
                        <fr:label>Without global errors</fr:label>
                    </fr:error-summary>
                </xh:td>
            </xh:tr>
        </xh:table>
        <xh:table>
            <xh:tr>
                <xh:td>
                    <fr:error-summary observer="validationArea" id="error-summary-global">
                        <fr:label>With global errors</fr:label>
                        <fr:errors nodeset="instance('errors')/error">
                            <fr:label ref="label"/>
                            <fr:alert ref="alert"/>
                        </fr:errors>
                    </fr:error-summary>
                </xh:td>
            </xh:tr>
        </xh:table>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some more digging, it turns out that the easiest way to circumvent this bug is to remove this part from the forms:

```
<fr:errors nodeset="instance('errors')/error">
    <fr:label ref="label"/>
    <fr:alert ref="alert"/>
</fr:errors>
```

After removing this part the error-summary renders as documented. It would mean that specifically the [global errors](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/error-summary#global-errors) rendering is broken.

The behavior in 2017.2 and 2018.1 is the same so it must have been broken between 3.9 and 2017.2.

Comment: Alexander, would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here, so we can look into it?

Comment: Done. Added it to the question.

Comment: Did this thing make it into an issue or is it under investigation? @avernet?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, somehow I missed your previous message. I've created issue [#3764](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3764) for this, and I'm not surprised that this regressed, since the error summary is mostly here to be used by forms created with Form Builder, and that Form Builder doesn't support global errors at this point.